# Apply a discount to all products in Magento

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento. I want to **provide a 30%  discount on all the products**. Also want **the old price to have a cross sign** on the frontend of my website.

Could anyone please help me to perform this task?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring Magento and belongs on the [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have to create a Catalog Price Rule. Go to Promotions/Catalog Price Rule and create a new rule. In "Actions" tab, set Apply by Percentage and set Discount Amount to 30.
Set all other fields as required.

This will apply 30% discount on all the products.

To get a cross sign on original price and display discounted price, you have to do some edits in **price.phtml** **list.phtml** and **view.phtml** in your theme, i.e

> app/design/PACKAGE/THEME/catalog/product/

To get original price, call **getPrice()** on product object. For discounted price, use **getFinalPrice()**

In your case, it should be **$_product->getPrice()** and **$_product->getFinalPrice()**

Apply CSS to put a strike mark on original price.